# Scientific concept into Spanish issue

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

I have the definition of a mathematical model in English and I have translated it, but I do not think it is correct, I can not figure it out how to translate a little part of it... 
Can you please suggest a better translation or just give a comment about the translation?

Original:

> PCA is a mathematical procedure that uses an orthogonal transformation to convert a set of observations of possibly correlated variables into a set of values of linearly uncorrelated variables called principal components. The number of principal components is less than or equal to the number of original variables. This transformation is defined in such a way that the first principal component has the largest possible variance **(that is, accounts for as much of the variability in the data as possible), and each succeeding component in turn has the highest variance possible under the constraint that it be orthogonal to (i.e., uncorrelated with) the preceding components.** Principal components are guaranteed to be independent only if the data set is jointly normally distributed. PCA is sensitive to the relative scaling of the original variables.

Translated version:

> PCA es un procedimiento matemático que utiliza una transformación ortogonal para convertir un conjunto de observaciones de variables posiblemente correlacionadas en un conjunto de valores de variables linealmente no correlacionadas denominados componentes principales. El número de componentes principales es menor o igual al número de variables originales. Esta transformación se define de tal manera que el primer componente principal tiene la varianza más grande posible **(...),  su vez cada componente subsiguiente tiene la mayor varianza posible cumpliendo la condición de que sean ortogonales (es decir, que no esten correlacionadas ) a los componentes anteriores. Los componentes principales serán independientes sólo si el conjunto de datos esta uniformemente distribuido. ...**

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Are you English or Spanish native speaker? Our preferred language in this SE site is Spanish, so if you are Spanish native speaker or good enough user as it seems, we encourage you to use Spanish! About your question, it's perfectly OK to ask about certain vocabulary that wouldn't appear in a dictionary. However, questions about "check my translation" are out of the site. Please, read our [FAQ].

Comment: You can ask the translations for each specific term you want to know, even in separate questions (very useful for future users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PCA = *ACP (Análisis de componentes principales)*

(fuente: [http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Análisis_de_componentes_principales](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lisis_de_componentes_principales))
Ver este artículo en wikipedia realmente te podría ayudar mucho a construir la más exacta traducción posible adaptada al lenguaje matemático.

> orthogonal transformation = *transformación ortogonal*

Puede utilizarse *transformación ortogonal*; no obstante, casi siempre se dice *transformación lineal.*

> linearly uncorrelated variables = *Variables linealmente independientes*

(fuente: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependencia_e_independencia_lineal)

> correlated or uncorrelated = *correlacionado* o *no correlacionado*

Puede decirse *correlacionado* o *no correlacionado* pero en español, se utilizan más los términos matemáticos exactos *dependientes* o *independientes*. (Para variables independientes muchas veces se utiliza **independientes entre si**.)

> jointly normally distributed = *distribución normal multivariante* o ***distribución gaussiana multivariante***

(fuente: [http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribución_normal_multivariante](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_normal_multivariante))

Aquí una lista con los nombres de las distribuciones más utilizadas: [http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribución_de_probabilidad#Distribuciones_de_variable_continua](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_probabilidad#Distribuciones_de_variable_continua)

Answer (score 3):

Mi traducción libre sería:

PCA es un procedimiento matemático que utiliza una transformación ortogonal para convertir un conjunto de observaciones de variables posiblemente correlacionadas en un conjunto de valores de variables linealmente no correlacionadas, llamadas componentes principales. El número de componentes principales es menor o igual que el número de variables originales. Esta transformación está definida de tal manera que el primer componente principal tiene la mayor varianza posible (es decir, cuenta con tanta de la variabilidad de los datos como sea posible), y cada componente subsiguiente a su vez tiene la mayor varianza posible bajo la condición que esta es ortogonal a (i.e. no tiene correlación con) los componentes precedentes. Se garantiza que los componentes principales son independientes solo si el conjunto de datos tiene una distribución conjunta normal. PCA es sensible a la escala relativa de las variables originales.

Los puntos de mayor duda son:

- *a set of observations of possibly correlated variables*. Lo he traducido como *un conjunto de observaciones de variables posiblemente correlacionadas*, pero hay algo que no me suena natural, es un conjunto de observaciones o un conjunto de variables que se observan?
- *that it **be** orthogonal to*. Lo he traducido como *que esta **es** ortogonal a*, pero no me queda muy claro el uso del verbo *to be* en esta forma en el Inglés. La traducción *que esta sea ortogonal a* o *que esta esté ortogonal a* tampoco me satisfacen, pues en mi opinión no quedaría claro que esta es una condición que *siempre se cumple* al utilizar el método (que es lo que yo comprendo del texto en inglés).
- *jointly normally distributed*. Lo he traducido como *distribución conjunta normal*, pero no soy matemático y no se el término correcto en español para describir esta propiedad del conjunto. El término *[distribución normal](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_normal)* no parece admitir el calificativo de *conjunta*, por lo que habría que ver cuidadosamente la manera de traducirlo para que sea técnicamente aceptable.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que se realiza una observacion de variables que quiza no esten correlacionadas,  por eso lo de "a un conjunto de observaciones de variables posiblemente correlacionadas"

Comment: El termino correcto es "distribución normal conjunta"

Comment: @cMinor el término correcto es distibución normal multivariante o distibución gaussiana multivariante (aunque algunos utilicen distribución normal conjunta)

Comment: Perfecto gracias

Comment: @cMinor mira la respuesta que puse debajo puede serte útil.

Comment: Es más preciso utilizar dependiente por correlacionada e independiente por no correlacionada. Sin embargo en párrafos donde se repita lo puedes utilizar como sinónimos.